# remove last n characters from a varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to remove the last n characters from a string. I tried this:

```
replace( str, right(str, 3), '' )
```

But it fails on str where the pattern repeats more than once. 888106106. In this case I get 888, instead of 888106

Now I am using

```
left (str, length(str)-3)
```

Is there a more efficient away of achieving this?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd think a simple `LEFT` is not efficient, or how it's supposed to be more efficient, or why that would matter in the first place.

Comment: the source table has a lot of rows. I just want to make sure I am using the optimal SQL for creating the VIEW on top of this table.

Comment: Are they all numbers stored as varchar?

Comment: yes, they are all numbers stored in a varchar.

Comment: What if the number is only 3 characters long? What should the expected output be?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, that's the most effective way.

Note that you should do one of:

- assert that all input strings will be length>2 [a bit lazy]
- handle the error where 1 of the rows has a length<3 and the query terminates early [a bit shoddy]
- use a case statement to handle the case where length < 3 [the preferred approach]

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(str) > 2 THEN LEFT(str, LENGTH(str) - 3)
        ELSE str 
    END
```

Other flavours of SQL you may have to work without the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy a `regex` based solution:

```
regexp_replace(str,'...$','')
```

It will leave strings with < 3 characters unchanged

Answer (score 1):

So checking that LEFT and/or SUBSTR work equally (I assume LEFT is faster):

```
select  
    column1 
    ,left(column1, length(column1) -3) as r1
    ,substr(column1, 0, length(column1) -3) as r2
from values
    ('abc123')
    ,('ab123')
    ,('a123')
    ,('123')
    ,('12')
    ,('1')
    ,('')
    ,(null);
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | abc | abc |
| ab123 | ab | ab |
| a123 | a | a |
| 123 | null | null |
| 12 | null | null |
| 1 | null | null |
| '' | null | null |
| null | null | null |

so no checks are needed, nice to know.

if you do some perf testing:

```
create database test;
create schema test.test;

create or replace table test.test.many_string as
select seq8()::text as a
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 10000000));

ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = false;

select sum(length(left(a, length(a) -3))) from test.test.many_string;
select sum(length(substr(a, 0, length(a) -3))) from test.test.many_string;
```

after running them both a couple of times on my x-small, I get results in the order of 300ms, so these are equal.

So it seems you have a fast solution, and easy to read.